# Установка зависимостей npm без доступа к интернету

Tags: reactjs, npm

Хотел бы освоить react нашел хорошую статью, но там надо установить какие то пакеты, как их можно установить на рабочем компьютере у которого нет прямого выхода в интернет, можно ли как то скачать дистрибутивы из интернета.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm не подойдет?

Answer (score 3):

Можно!

Как вариант, собрать дистрибутив где либо (например на домашнем компьютере или c9.io). Проверить на работоспособность и выкачать архивом.

Можно выкачивать по отдельности каждый компонент, **НО!** Каждый компонент может (и будет скорее всего) иметь свои зависимости. Так что эта цепочка займет немыслимую тонну времени.

А вообще работать с данным типом среды (пакетными менеджерами) без интернета считается бредом. По крайней мере хоть раз надо выкачать все зависимости через пакеты